# Sequence of totally bounded sets

Tags: metric-spaces

I've been trying to solve this question for a while now:

> If $\{E_n\}$ is a sequence of totally bounded sets such that diam $E_n \rightarrow 0$, show that $\cup_{n=1}^{\infty} E_n$ is totally bounded.

I don't seem to understand what to do or how to solve this; please help.

Also, if the diam $E_n$ is going to 0, for any $r>0$, won't there occur a point after which the sets will be bounded by 1 ball of radius $r$, so if they all are disjoint, the total number of balls will be infinite, leading to a contradiction. I think my logic here is flawed somewhere.

Thank you so much

Comment: The statement isn't true. In $\Bbb R$ with the usual metric, taking $E_n=\{n\}$ gives a counterexample.

Comment: That's a valid argument; so I believe the author must have made a mistake. Will my reasoning also have worked?

Comment: Just to say, I got this question from John B. Conway's book "A Course in Point Set Topology" pg. 29.